# Composite Baseline Concept applied to DVCS Mercurial/Git

Tags: dvcs

I come from the IBM Rational ClearCase world (UCM and all that..) and as I remember the concept on Composite Baselines i wonder if there is something out there that has the same purpose for DVCS.

I understand that Mercurial/Git are "Get All the Code Base or nothing". But could be something that could manage the tags/baselines for different repositories and be able to manage those as composite baselines.

systemX/release-1  = subsystemA-repo/release-20 +  subsystemB-repo/release-18 + subsystemC-repo/release-2

This mechanism will abstract the was i can query baselines to systemX-releasex and get the appropriate tags from the dvcs repositories.

Any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

`git submodules`, `hg subrepos`, etc.

Comment: I will try this approach with 3 mercurial sub-repositories and see how it goes today.